# Python regex: getting text from html elements with similar structure

Tags: python, regex

For some reason I need to use regular expressions to extract some data from a web site. The data has similar HTML structure, only text differs. 
For simplicity I show it this way:

```
p = '<div class="col-xs-6"><p>Gender:</p></div><div class="col-xs-6"><a href="/skor/herr">Herr</a>, <a href="/skor/dam">Dam</a></div>'
t = '<div class="col-xs-6"><p>Kategori:</p></div><div class="col-xs-6"><a href="/skor/kangor-boots">Boots</a></div>'
s = p + t
```

I am only interested in 'Gender' which means I want to extract 'Herr' and 'Dam' only.

So far I came up with two options - both not working:

`m = re.findall("Gender.+?<div.+?>([\w ]+)<\/.+?<\/div>", s, re.DOTALL)`

gives:

['Herr']

I guess because it is non-greedy

But if I make it greedy:

```
re.findall("Gender.+?<div.+>([\w ]+)<\/.+?<\/div>", s, re.DOTALL)
```

It returns:

['Boots']

So I am struggling to figure out how to get both 'Herr' and 'Dam' and nothing more?

Comment: So if you know beforehand that only "Herr" and "Dam" will be what you want, why not search only for this? Unless you want to generalize this for other possible values.

Comment: Exactly. I want to generalize this for other possible values of 'Gender' and not only

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) in such a way

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a='<div class="col-xs-6"><p>Gender:</p></div><div class="col-xs-6"><a href="/skor/herr">Herr</a>, <a href="/skor/dam">Dam</a></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,"html.parser")
if 'Gender' in (str(soup.findAll('div'))):
    for ana in soup.findAll('div'):
        for i in ana.findAll('a'):
            print(i.next_element)
```

Output:

```
Herr
Dam
```

I would recommend to add name attribute to the divs so it would be easier to determine the correct tags

```
p = '<div name="Gender" class="col-xs-6"><p>Gender:</p></div><div name="Gender" class="col-xs-6"><a href="/skor/herr">Herr</a>, <a href="/skor/dam">Dam</a></div>'
t = '<div class="col-xs-6"><p>Kategori:</p></div><div class="col-xs-6"><a href="/skor/kangor-boots">Boots</a></div>'
a = p + t

soup = BeautifulSoup(a,"html.parser")
for ana in soup.findAll('div',{"name":"Gender"}):
    for i in ana.findAll('a'):
        print(i.next_element)
```

Output:

```
 Herr
 Dam
```

Comment: I know about BS.  However for some reason in this case I would prefer regex based solution. I don't have a solid knowledge in regular expressions but I was under impression that almost everything is possible using them in terms of text matching and extraction. I hope there is a solution to do that with RE.

Comment: the problem with using regex is forming a generalized rule is different. Can you modify the tags with name attribute only attached to divs which are associated with gender then it would be a lot easier and would make more sense